# Need suggestion for a bulletin board engine, Java based, JSP/JSF, and free

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script, community-management

Could you please advise me of a bulletin board engine that is based in Java? And for its scripting language, either JSP or JSF.

I'd also prefer it to use Spring, Hibernate and/or other frameworks.

It would be better, still, if it's free.

Answer (score 3):

[JavaBB](http://www.javabb.org/) is probably the biggest one?

[mvnForum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mvnforum/) is open source

Comment: hi, Wil, i more interested in bulletin board where people can buy and sale different goods, and JavaBB is a classical forum as i understand